# Create GitTag for every PR merged to Master Branch

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I was trying to automate creating new Git Tag every time a PR is merged to master branch. We have a master branch and whenever PR raised against the master branch is approved and merged then new Tag should be created with same version number every time. Is this possible in Github? If so please guide how this can be achieved.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create a workflow that triggers when there is a push to mastar branch. If the repo only allows push to the main branch via pull request, then something like this would do what you want:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  tag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - run: git tag <YOUR TAG HERE>
    - run: git push
```

you can also check already done solutions, like this one: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/tag-version-commit